# Postman/Insomnia returns 200 but Java client returns 404 on re-submission

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I am developing a client in Spring Boot which **POST** some data to remote REST service and retrieves the result. I am able to submit it to remote service and getting a **SUCCESS** response in first attempt.

But on subsequent attempts, I am getting 404 error while submitting the same request to remote. I am able to achieve the same with Postman or Insomnia Tools but not able to understand what is that different element which Java is missing.

This snippet works fine if I restart the server which means something wrongly stuck with my application which is preventing to get it **POST**ed to remote service.

Here is the snippet

```
public static ApiResponse postRequest(String url, String apiId, Token token, Product product, String data, Object type)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PolicyResponse mResponse = null;
    apiError apiError = null;
    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
    InputStream responseStream = null;


    try {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("User-Agent", "MY Framework"+new Date() + new Random().nextDouble());
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

        if(token != null) {
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());
        }
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.setCacheControl("no-cache");

        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(data,headers);

        logger.info("Headers " + headers);
        if(token != null) {
            logger.info("Token " + token.getAccessToken());
        }
        logger.info("PolicyURL :: " + url);
        logger.info("API ID :: " + apiId);
        logger.info("Request Data :: " + data);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity <JsonNode>response = restTemplate.exchange(url, 
                                                                HttpMethod.POST, 
                                                                request,
                                                                JsonNode.class); 

        logger.debug("Response Data :: " + response.getBody());
        mapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);

        if (null != response) {
            apiResponse.setApiId(apiId);
            if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK || response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
                apiResponse.setHttpResponse(response.getBody().toString());
                apiResponse.setJsonNode(response.getBody());
                logger.debug(response.getBody().toString());
            } else {
                logger.debug("Error Response " + response.getBody());

                apiError apiError = mapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), new TypeReference<apiError>() {
                });
                apiResponse.setHttpResponse(response.getBody().toString());

                apiResponse.setHttpResponseMessage(apiError.getMessage());
            }
        }
        apiResponse.setHttpStatusCode(String.valueOf(response.getStatusCode()));


    } 
    catch(HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
        logger.error(hcee.getCause());
        logger.error(hcee.getResponseBodyAsString());

        apiResponse.setHttpStatusCode(String.valueOf(hcee.getRawStatusCode()));
        apiResponse.setHttpResponse(hcee.getResponseBodyAsString());
        apiResponse.setHttpResponseMessage(hcee.getMessage());
    }

    finally {
        if(responseStream != null) {
            responseStream.close();
        }
    }
    return apiResponse;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake where somehow different thread was aletring the URL on the fly and that was causing issue.

I debugged it and fixed it.

Thanks for everyone who all were involved.